# Different output online than on my localhost (Adds backslashes)

Tags: php, ajax, localhost, backslash

I've written a simple news-script, with implemented AJAX that let's you switch between different contents on this news. These contents of the "subpages" are in seperate HTML Files.

Now on my localhost it's works perfectly, but online it adds backslashes to the code so for example img tags don't work!

Here's a screenshot of what the code does online:

http://img6.imagebanana.com/img/3e6u5lmx/Bildschirmfoto20120721um19.33.21.png

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable `magic_quotes_gpc` in your `php.ini` configuration file.